# Chi square proof with Exp law

Tags: statistics

For an exercice in Statistics,

For $ X \sim Exp(\theta)$

I have to proof that :

$ (\dfrac{2} {\theta}) \sum_{i=1}^{12} X_i \sim X^2(24)$

And with this result, I have to found a best critic region with $\alpha = 0.1$

Is there anyone that can help with the proof. I can do the rest.

(Sorry for English terms that not matching, my course is in french)

Comment: As I know for an $Exp(\theta)$ the $\sigma^2 = \theta$, but I don't see how to retrieve Chi-square.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is (i) Find or look up the moment generating function of the exponential; (ii) Calculate the $12$-th power of the mgf (trivial); Look up or find the mgf of the appropriate $\chi^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer as you said @André Nicolas,

With the moment generating function of the exponential and a small trick, you can have the moment generating function of the chi-square with 2n degree.